# JSF subTable Expand/Collapse

Tags: javascript, jsf, richfaces

I am running Rich Faces 3.x, and I have a subTable within a dataTable which I would like to toggle the show/hide preferably using Java script.  What I have so far...

```
<c:set var="plusIcon" value="/sprites/images/collapsed.gif"/>
<c:set var="minusIcon" value="/sprites/images/expanded.gif"/>
...
<rich:dataTable id="bookList_dt" [...]>
<rich:column>
    <h:graphicImage id="expand" value="/images/expanded.gif" onclick="toggleDetails(this);"/>
</rich:column>
 <rich:column>
  <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
  <h:outputText value="#{_item.bookId}"/>
 </rich:column>
[...]
 <rich:subTable value="#{_item.relatedVersions}  var="_relatedItem" id="relatedVersionsList">
  <rich:column>
   <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
   <h:outputText value="#{_relatedItem.bookId}"/>
  </rich:column>
[...]
 </rich:subTable>
</rich:dataTable>
```

And my JavaScript so far...

```
function toggleDetails(image) {
    var detailsId = image.id.substring(0, image.id.lastIndexOf(':')) + ':relatedVersionsList';
    var details = document.getElementById(detailsId);
    if (details.style.display == 'none') {
        details.style.display = 'block';
        image.src = '#{minusIcon}';
    } else {
        details.style.display = 'none';
        image.src = '#{plusIcon}';
    }
```

Currently I get an error, stating that details is null

EDIT: I've heard that using HtmlSubTable class of the subtable might work, but I don't see any examples of it's use, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed below is fairly straightforward: find all successive `tr` elements and toggle visibility of any element until an element with class `rich-table-row` is reached:

```
<h:graphicImage ... onclick="jQuery(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr').each(function() {
           if(jQuery(this).is('.rich-table-row')) {return false;}
           jQuery(this).toggle();})"/>
```

The solution was tested using RichFaces 3.3.3.Final and its built-in jQuery library version 1.3 that doesn't contain the easier [`nextUntil(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) function that was introduced in jQuery 1.4.

That said, if you can shift to Richfaces 4.x there are some standard solutions to your issue by using [`<rich:collapsibleSubTable>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/rich/collapsibleSubTable.html) and [`<rich:collapsibleSubTableToggler>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/rich/collapsibleSubTableToggler.html) components ([showcase example](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=subTableToggleControl&skin=blueSky)). Also, it is worth noting that in Richfaces 4.x there is no such component as `<rich:subTable>` anymore.

Comment: The subTable is now disappearing :) Is there a simple way to change the icon as well?

Comment: For smooth (dis)appearance consider enabling jQuery effects like fade in / fade out, etc. As for changing the icon I'd suggest to load a sprite image containing both extended and collapsed images and additionally toggle `background-position`, i.e. `jQuery(this).toggleClass('expanded')`.

Comment: I don't quite follow.  I have both the images in c:Set local variables, is it possible to switch the image.source in some sort of if/else integrated with the jQuery provided?

Comment: The values you set are not available on the client side. To toggle the factual image you've got two options: (1) have two css classes with the images preloaded and toggle them in onclick or have one css class and toggle background position in onclick and apply this class to e.g. a div element instead of an img element and (2) load two graphic images (expanded/collapsed) and show/hide the one or the other in onclick.